# Max of date from three tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, controller

I have three tables in database

```
tableA
tableB
tableC
```

All these three table have document_date.

```
$date1 = '2023-01-01'; 
$date2 = '2023-08-01';
```

I need eloquent with model for

```
max(
 ( max of document_date in table A wherebetween $date1 and $date2), 
 ( max of document_date in table B wherebetween $date1 and $date2), 
 ( max of document_date in table C wherebetween $date1 and $date2)
)
```

The result should be **one date**.

Comment: Do you need max date from all these three tables? *Un clear what you are asking for. Add an example if you can't elaborate more. (like this is the data, this I need etc.. )*

Comment: what is the relation between those tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$date1 = '2023-01-01'; 
$date2 = '2023-08-01'; 

$maxDate = max(
    TableA::whereBetween('document_date', [$date1, $date2])->max('document_date'),
    TableB::whereBetween('document_date', [$date1, $date2])->max('document_date'),
    TableC::whereBetween('document_date', [$date1, $date2])->max('document_date')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should join those tables then use [mysql greatest](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_greatest.asp) function:

```
$maxDate = TableA::join('tableB', 'tableA.user_id', '=', 'tableB.user_id')
    ->join('tableC', 'tableB..user_id', '=', 'tableC.user_id')
    ->selectRaw('tableA.user_id,GREATEST(MAX(tableA.document_date), MAX(tableB.document_date), MAX(tableC.document_date)) as final_max_date')
    ->groupBy('tableA.user_id')
->get();
```

I think it need some tweaks to match your DB, but there is the main idea

Answer (score 0):

I'd execute three separate queries selecting the largest date per table and then checking which one is the highest using plain PHP. Otherwise your queries will quickly become a tangled mess. Unless this is for some highly optimized production application, the premature optimization will definitely not outweigh the speed gained by combining it into a singular query.

**Example**

```
function maxFromTable(array $models) {
    $numbers = [];

    foreach($models as $model => $field) {
        $numbers[] = $model::latest($field)->field;
    }
    
    return max($numbers);
}

$models = [
    tableA::class => 'document_date',
    .....
];

maxFromTable($models);
```

*Psuedo-code*

**Pro's**

1. Easier to extent
2. More readable

**Cons**

1. Slower
2. More database overhead